# How can i speed up this combinatorical problem?

Tags: python, performance, combinatorics

I have the following problem: I want do calculate something that can be considered a distance between team trajectories in a 5 (v 5) player game to in the end do clustering on these trajectories.

I have a working setup. However, it is extremely slow to calculate the distances/clusters for any appreciable number of trajectories.

The setup and the steps i am currently taking are as follows.

The game map can be segmented into a finite number of "tiles" as shown here: [image]. The distances from each tile to every other tile is precomputed and stored in a json file with the following structure:

area_distance_matrix[map_name][area1id][area2id][dist_type(euclidean,graph,geodesic)]
This step takes a bit but is not the bottleneck here as it does not scale with the number of trajectories i want to look at.

So now if i want to know the distance between any two players i just look at which area they are in (also precomputed at this stage) and just grab their distance from this loaded json file.

Next to determine the distance between any team of 5 players (at a specific time) i do the following: I determine every possible assignment of players from the one team to players from the other team. (So for 3 player each ((1,1),(2,2),(3,3)), ((1,2),(2,1),(3,3)) and so on. Then i calculate the every average distance of the pairs for each assignment and keep the smallest one.

```py
def position_state_distance(
    map_name: str,
    position_array_1: npt.NDArray,
    position_array_2: npt.NDArray,
    distance_type: DistanceType = "geodesic",
) -> float:
    """Calculates a distance between two game states based on player positions.

    Args:
        map_name (string): Map to search
        position_array_1 (numpy array): Numpy array with shape (2|1, 5, 1)
            with the first index indicating the team, the second the player
            and the third the tile.
        position_array_2 (numpy array): Numpy array with shape (2|1, 5, 1)
            with the first index indicating the team, the second the player
            and the third the tile.
        distance_type (string, optional): String indicating how the distance between
            two player positions should be calculated.
            Options are "geodesic", "graph" and "euclidean". Defaults to 'geodesic'

    Returns:
        A float representing the distance between these two game states
    """
    position_array_1, position_array_2 = _check_arguments_position_distance(
        map_name, position_array_1, position_array_2, distance_type
    )
    pos_distance: float = 0
    # Get the minimum mapping distance for each side separately
    for team in range(position_array_1.shape[0]):
        side_distance = float("inf")
        # Generate all possible mappings between players from array1 and array2.
        # Map player1 from array1 to player1 from array2 and
        # player2's to each other or match player1's with player2's and so on
        for mapping in itertools.permutations(
            range(position_array_1.shape[1]), position_array_2.shape[1]
        ):
            cur_dist: float = 0
            for player2, player1 in enumerate(mapping):
                this_dist = 0
                area1 = position_array_1[team][player1][0]
                area2 = position_array_2[team][player2][0]
                this_dist = min(
                    AREA_DIST_MATRIX[map_name][str(area1)][str(area2)][distance_type],
                    AREA_DIST_MATRIX[map_name][str(area2)][str(area1)][distance_type],
                )
                if this_dist == float("inf"):
                    this_dist = sys.maxsize / 6
                cur_dist += this_dist / len(mapping)
            side_distance = min(side_distance, cur_dist)
        pos_distance += side_distance / position_array_1.shape[0]
    return pos_distance
```

Now for the trajectory distance i can either average/sum the team distances at each point in time or do dynamic time warping (which is n^2 in the number of time steps).

So effectively:

```py
def area_trajectory_distance(
    trajectory_array_1: np.ndarray,
    trajectory_array_2: np.ndarray,
) -> float:
    length = max(len(trajectory_array_1), len(trajectory_array_2))
    dist = 0
    for time in range(length):
        dist += position_state_distance(
            position_array_1=trajectory_array_1[time]
            if time in range(len(trajectory_array_1))
            else trajectory_array_1[-1],
            position_array_2=trajectory_array_2[time]
            if time in range(len(trajectory_array_2))
            else trajectory_array_2[-1],
            dist_matrix=dist_matrix,
        )
    return dist / length
```

And then finally to do the clustering i take all of the (thousands) of trajectories i want to cluster and precompute a distance matrix for them to give to the clustering algorithm.

```
def get_traj_matrix_area(
    precompute_array: np.ndarray, dist_matrix: dict, dtw: bool
) -> np.ndarray:
    """Precompute the distance matrix for all trajectories of areas

    Args:
        precompute_array: Numpy array of trajectories for which to compute the distance matrix

    Returns:
        Numpy array of distances between trajectories
    """
    precomputed = np.zeros((len(precompute_array), len(precompute_array)))
    for i in range(len(precompute_array)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(precompute_array)):
            precomputed[i][j] = area_trajectory_distance(
                precompute_array[i], precompute_array[j]
            )
    precomputed += precomputed.T
    return precomputed
```

To then finally do

```
kmed = KMedoids(n_clusters=n_cluster, metric="precomputed").fit(
            precomputed
       )
```

And now my question which parts i could improve to reduce the time it takes for the whole procedure and how to best do that.

So far i have tried using numba and that has given me a bit of a performance boost but it doesnt play nice with itertools so in the end it helped a bit but wasnt enough.

```
         2511861870 function calls (2460436306 primitive calls) in 1281.971 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 66365512  132.039    0.000  567.527    0.000 typeddict.py:176(__getitem__)
  4995000  113.294    0.000 1198.658    0.000 nav_utils.py:648(fast_token_state_distance)
 66364936  100.695    0.000  183.750    0.000 typedlist.py:365(__getitem__)
 66365512   90.456    0.000  194.496    0.000 typeddict.py:37(_getitem)
37169228/18182557   50.793    0.000  287.301    0.000 iterables.py:1278(multiset_permutations)
16755452/8377726   48.454    0.000  105.217    0.000 sorting.py:10(default_sort_key)
 66366790   47.594    0.000  215.832    0.000 dispatcher.py:724(typeof_pyval)
 66364936   42.223    0.000   58.534    0.000 typedlist.py:90(_getitem)
36438158/14252492   40.854    0.000  212.264    0.000 sorting.py:203(ordered)
165915291   40.810    0.000   40.810    0.000 serialize.py:30(_numba_unpickle)
66368504/66368412   37.567    0.000   99.990    0.000 functools.py:904(wrapper)
 66368411   37.499    0.000  163.191    0.000 typeof.py:27(typeof)
 66368504   31.599    0.000   52.594    0.000 functools.py:818(dispatch)
 33183044   27.201    0.000   79.542    0.000 typeddict.py:77(_from_meminfo_ptr)
 25370390   26.705    0.000   26.711    0.000 {built-in method builtins.sum}
 33183069   23.493    0.000   40.857    0.000 typeddict.py:107(__init__)
  8377726   22.370    0.000   40.692    0.000 sorting.py:180(_nodes)
 12353052   18.566    0.000   29.054    0.000 sympify.py:102(sympify)
 66377100   16.215    0.000   16.233    0.000 weakref.py:414(__getitem__)
132734582   16.106    0.000   16.106    0.000 typeddict.py:160(_numba_type_)
 50274265   15.941    0.000   21.666    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:405(parent)
```

Comment: This question, while not off-topic for StackOverflow, might be better-received over at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ? In a nutshell, the former is for when you're having trouble when you're in front of your editor and the latter is for when you're having trouble when you're in front of a whiteboard planning the solution. This seems like arguably in the latter category :)

Comment: Run a profiler or tell us where is the most expensive step. Also, for code clarity, you would be better adding some data structure (NamedTuple or structured np.ndarray), it would be easier to understand (even if there is a great effort for documentation in your code). Also, I hardly understand why you need n! combinations. To me, since your "distance" is asymetric, you would need n(n-1) combinations. I probably miss something.

Comment: Did you do profiling? If yes, where is most of the computation time spent?

Comment: Kmedoids is cuadratic [wiki: Kmedoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids). Why using euclidean distance in this map, shouldn't it be taxicab?

Comment: @Memristor the main part of the runtime isnt the kmedoids at the end with the matrix precomuted.

Euclidean is just the easiest to compute, buts it not the one i am actually using. I am mainly using the "geodesic" option because you cant simply do manhattan as this isnt a checker board and the graph is also weighted. There are some places where you can go from a to b but not the reverse. But that part also isnt the bottleneck as those distances are precomputed anyway and fixed per map.

Comment: Two immediate improvements when you have nested loops are list comprehensions and vectorization, just to give you something.

Comment: @anatolyg i added the results from running the script with cProfile.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop has this expression

```
AREA_DIST_MATRIX[map_name][str(area1)][str(area2)][distance_type]
```

which looks non-optimal. `AREA_DIST_MATRIX` looks like a dictionary (because it's indexed by strings), while it should be an array. I interpret it as the cause for the extreme time consumed by `__getitem__`.

Comment: Yeah, its loaded from a json file. So i should probably transform that to 2-D numpy array first like `dist_matrix_for_map_name_and_distance_type[area1, area2]`.

Problem is that the area1 and 2 ids are not contigous. But i also thing they arent too sparse. So it should probably work.